Configuring Docker Network on Ubuntu 24.04 Host
I'm having trouble configuring Docker networking on my Ubuntu 24.04 host, and I could really use some help.
Environment:

Host OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Host IP: 10.78.20.20 (running on an ESXi machine)
Docker is installed and running fine.
I am new to Docker.

I can successfully run a Docker container and access it through the host IP (10.78.20.20). However, I want to assign a different IP to this container, such as 10.78.20.40.
Here is a snippet from my docker-compose.yml where I attempted to set up a custom bridge network:
networks:
  custom_bridge:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.78.20.0/24
          gateway: 10.78.20.1

services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    networks:
      custom_bridge:
        ipv4_address: 10.78.20.40

Unfortunately, this configuration didn't work as expected. The container is still not accessible via the new IP address.
I tried several other guides and tutorials from the internet, but none of them solved my issue.
Question:
How can I properly configure Docker to assign a specific IP address (10.78.20.40) to my container on my current setup?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Without Docker, how do you assign IP addresses to specific processes, and why?  The ports: setting has an optional field to specify the host IP address to listen on for published ports and that might help on a multi-homed system.

The problem has been resolved, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
The solution I implemented was to add an alias to the network interface and, in the docker-compose file, specify the IP address along with the port.
Thank you again for your help!
